# Is there a good drawing tool that can draw property graph in modeling?

Tags: neo4j

I like those example graphs mentioned in Neo4j's blogs and the Neo4j tutorial book. However, I can't find one tool that can draw the graph in modeling stage. The Neo4j Browser doesn't seem to be a good tool to do that.

I would appreciate a lot if there is some recommendation on this.  One graph example is here:
https://neo4j.com/blog/data-modeling-pitfalls/

Those graphs look good.  What tool can draw it?

Answer (score 1):

I think those are hand-drawn.

My go to tool is still arrows, which works really well for quick modeling.

http://www.apcjones.com/arrows/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkD1agLtQ4I

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSjlUoFQdos

Comment: Is there  a way to delete a node or relationship in the drawing?

Comment: @marlon you just double click on them and theres a delete button

Comment: @SledgeHammer, the apcjones tool doesn' support Chinese. Do you know whether there is a quick way to fix that?