# Are there any collaborative data modelling tools for a property graph model that can import into neo4j

Tags: neo4j, data-modeling, graph-modelling-language, property-graph

I'm looking for a good whiteboarding tool for the [property graph model](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-modeling/). I realise this is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59417947/is-there-a-good-drawing-tool-that-can-draw-property-graph-in-modeling), however I'd like it to be collaborative & the output to export to a standard graph database format so can be [imported](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/import/).

**Context**

Team is breaking down requirements to identify if a graph based database structure is a good fit. While I think in person whiteboarding is the best approach for collaborating, this is during COVID so remote working is essential.

Comment: Unfortunately, tool/product recommendation questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks David, realise that, I'm trying trying to understand the best practices in visualising  graph based architecture at this time. Perhaps I should look at restructuring the question.